# Comparing primitive types

Tags: java, compiler-errors, primitive-types

I have been asked

> Given the definitions of a, b and c below, select the expressions that compile successfully and evaluate to true.
>
> ```
> int a = 1;
> char b = 'a';
> boolean c = false;
> ```

So I used a simple

```
if (expression)
{System.out.println("True");}
else
{System.out.println("False");}
```

Is this right?

```
c==a         //false
!c || a      //false
b >= a       //true
c = a        //false
a - b - 96   //false
a + b > 0    //true
c = true     //true
a < b        //true
```

Does this look ok?

Comment: From the `System.out.println` I take it the question is about Java? It's important when answering what will compile and what won't.

Comment: Sorry I always forget to state the language i'm using. You are correct, it is Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `c==a`: doesn't compile, `int` can't be compared to `boolean`.
- `!c || a`: doesn't compile, `boolean || int` isn't allowed
- `b >= a`: compiles, evaluates to `true`
- `c = a`: doesn't compile, can't assign an `int` value to a `boolean`
- `a - b - 96`: compiles, evaluates to -192
- `a + b > 0`: compiles, evaluates to `true`
- `c = true`:  compiles, evaluates to `true` (and assigns `true` to `c`)
- `a < b`: compiles, evaluates to `true`

Comment: Thanks for this Joachim. I appreciate you taking the time out to help!

Answer (score 0):

If an expression doesn't compile, what do you think the output of

```
if (expression) 
   {System.out.println("True");} 
else 
   {System.out.println("False");}
```

would be?

For those that do compile, then yes, you're right.

Comment: Thanks alot Luchian, appreciate the help!